# Creating a simple unit of work with Entity Framework and no repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been trying to implement a .NET MVC Unit of Work API (rather than creating a separate repository), but it doesn't feel right. Am I going about this the correct way?

Following advice from [here](https://rob.conery.io/2014/03/03/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/).

BaseController

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
    {
        protected DBEntities _dbEntities;

        protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            _dbEntities = new DBEntities();
        }

        protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            _dbEntities.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

MyController

```
public class MyController : BaseController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage PutMyObject(int id, int id2)
    {
        if (id != 0)
        {
            var myObject = _dbEntities.MyObjects.Where(x => x.id == id);
            if (myObject.Count() > 0)
            {
                MyObject temp = myObject.SingleOrDefault();
                temp.Processed = true;
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /* do some other stuff */
        }
    }             

}
```

My thinking around this is that the controller action is a single Unit of Work. The database connection is opened when the controller action starts, and SaveChanges is called once the response is returned.

Am I going about this in the correct manner? Do I need to dispose of `_dbentities` after `SaveChanges` is called within the `BaseController`?

Answer (score 4):

I can be very short about this:

1. Single responsibility: a controller shouldn't *also* have Unit of Work responsibilities. The context itself is the perfect Unit of Work.
2. You don't always need `SaveChanges`
3. Use dependency injection.

I like to see controllers as light-weight doorways to web-independent service methods. The services have their own `DbContext` and execute `SaveChanges` where necessary and, thus, can be used in other applications than just MVC/Web API applications. Controllers receive services by dependency injection.